# Returning a Pexpect Spawn Instance From Function

Tags: python, function, pexpect

I am using the python pexpect module to log onto a network device. I have placed the required code into a function and it operates successfully, however after the function is finished I want to keep using the instance further in my script. I am not sure what I need to return from the function for this to work.

Function

```
def logon(device):
    p = pexpect.spawn('ssh username@' + device, timeout=10)
    x = p.expect (['yes/no','password:'])
    if x==0:
            p.sendline('yes')
            y = p.expect(['password:'])
            if y==0:
                    p.sendline(PW)
                    z = p.expect(['#'])
                    if z==0:
                            print('Successfully logged onto ' + device)
            else:
                    print('Failed to log onto device ' + device)
    if x==1:
            p.sendline(PW)
            z = p.expect(['#'])
            if z==0:
                    print('Successfully logged onto ' + device)
            else:
                    print('Failed to log onto device ' + device)
    else:
            print('Failed to log onto device ' + device)
    return p 
logon(device)
p.sendline('show clock')
p.expect('#')
```

The function works as expected, I receive the message 'successfully logged onto device', and I thought passing the 'p' value back would allow me to continue working with the pexpect instance. But I receive the following error.

```
p.sendline('show clock')
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

Is there a way to pass everything back from function? Perhaps I am misunderstanding what I need to return from the function in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
logon(device)
```

do

```
p=logon(deive)
```

yes you can use the object returned by swapn anywhere

Comment: I tried that. Now when I do p.sendline('show clock') I receive the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendline'

Comment: @baz00r : That should work. Double check that you've got your function right (with the right indentation and everything), so that it always hits `return p` at the end.

Comment: Thomas, it does indeed work. After I changed the p=logon(device) I forgot to add the 'return p' on the function. It now seems to work now. Thanks so much.